# Parallelizing list filtering

Tags: python, dictionary, dask, dask-delayed, bag

I have a list of items that I need to filter based on some conditions. I'm wondering whether Dask could do this filtering in parallel, as the list is very long (a few dozen million records).

Basically, what I need to do is this:

```py
items = [
    {'type': 'dog', 'weight': 10},
    {'type': 'dog', 'weight': 20},
    {'type': 'cat', 'weight': 15},
    {'type': 'dog', 'weight': 30},
]

def item_is_valid(item):
    item_is_valid = True

    if item['type']=='cat':
        item_is_valid = False
    elif item['weight']>20:
        item_is_valid = False
    # ...
    # elif for n conditions

    return item_is_valid

items_filtered = [item for item in items if item_is_valid(item)]
```

With Dask, what I have achieved to do is the following:

```py
def item_is_valid_v2(item):
    """Return the whole item if valid."""
    item_is_valid = True

    if item['type']=='cat':
        item_is_valid = False
    elif item['weight']>20:
        item_is_valid = False
    # ...
    # elif for n conditions
    
    if item_is_valid:
        return item

results = []
item = []
for item in items:
    delayed = dask.delayed(item_is_valid)(item)
    results.append(delayed)

results = dask.compute(*results)
```

However, the result I get contains a few `None` values, which then need to be filtered out somehow in a non-parallel way.

```
({'type': 'dog', 'weight': 10}, {'type': 'dog', 'weight': 20}, None, None)
```

Comment: Have you tried checking if the value is `None` *before* appending it to the list? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The items get appended lazily via Dask and once during computation everything happens within Dask, so I don't think you get to choose what items get appended. If it's possible I don't know how you'd go about doing that.

Comment: How fast do you need to be, and what exactly is in your condition ? filtering 48 million records with that condition only takes 6.7 seconds (which seems pretty quick). If your condition is accessing the same dictionary keys multiple times, you could make it faster by placing the values in variables. You could also obtain a small speed gain by using filter instead of a list comprehension: `result = [*filter(item_is_valid,items)]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the `bag` API will work you, this is a rough pseudo-code:

```
import dask.bag as db

bag = db.from_sequence() # or better yet read it from disk
result = bag.filter(item_is_valid) # note this uses the first version (bool)
```

To inspect if this is working, inspect the outcome of `result.take(5)` and if that is satisfactory:

```py
computed_result = result.compute()
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks!! I believe `bag.from_iterable` doesn't exist. Btw, I believe it's `bag.from_sequence`, feel free to change it so other people don't get confused. But thanks again for the solution!

Comment: Ha! Memory playing tricks on me, thanks, I'll update the answer.